# Summing values in nested list when item changes

Tags: python

I have some problem which has stumped my beginner-knowledge of python and I hope someone out there can point me in the correct direction.

I generated a nested list, each nested list consisting of two (sorry guys, my fault!) values, like:

```
[[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]
```

The first value always designates a day, the second one is always the value I am actually interested in. But I need to sum up all of these second values which occur on a given day as in: 
e.g. 0+2 on day 1, and 9 on day 2, and 0+8+1 on day 3

and generate a list which actually looks like `[[1,2][2,9][3,9]]`, again with each first value giving the day over which I summed and the second value as the sum of all values on this day.

I know this is a pretty basic problem and I would know how to solve it in e.g. gawk or fortran, but I want to learn how to do this the pythonic way. I looked into using zip/map but I do not know how to set it up for this specific problem. I hope someone out there can point me into the right direction

Comment: i found only two values.

Comment: what do you mean Avinash? I do not understand your comment, please be more specific.

Comment: You said each nested list consisting of 3 values but it seems your nested list holds 2 elements day and value.

Comment: @eko13 [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) can be used for this kind of problem. Are you able to write a solution for your problem in terms of `for` loops?

Comment: sorry, I ammended the post. My fault, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I know for-loops, I will read about list comprehensions and ask again if I run into troubles! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the key in a dictionary and store the counts in the values. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = [[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]
res = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] in res:
        res[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
        res[i[0]] = i[1]

print res
```

OUTPUT:

```
{1: 2, 2: 9, 3: 9}
```

This output is in dictionary format. You can turn it to list format as you like.

Comment: `i[0] in res` would be more efficient.

Comment: Good idea, I should have realized at once that keys could be the answer! Thank you all for your pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Problem's like this calls for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Particularly groupby, groups consecutive values with same keys, where keys can be specified by user. Nevertheless, in this case, key is trivial enough as indexing a particular element of a list, so that should be a reason enough to use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html). Finally, you can wrap up either as a functional (using map/imap) or as a generator expression based on your taste and choice.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, imap
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst=[[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]
>>> [[k, sum(imap(itemgetter(1), v))]
     for k, v in groupby(lst,key = itemgetter(0))]
[[1, 2], [2, 9], [3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on m170897017's technique:

```
a = [[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]

result = {}
for day, val in a:
    if day not in result:
       result[day] = 0
    result[day] += val

print result

#Convert back into a list
print [list(t) for t in result.items()]
```

**output**

```
{1: 2, 2: 9, 3: 9}
[[1, 2], [2, 9], [3, 9]]
```

If you're using Python 2.7 or later, you could also use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Another possibility is to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which has been available since Python 2.5.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]

result = defaultdict(int)
for day, val in a:
    result[day] += val

print [list(t) for t in result.items()]
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2], [2, 9], [3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using defaultdict ...

```
from collections import defaultdict

dat = [[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]

d = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in dat: d[k] += v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `collections.OrderedDict` mapping `items`  to list:

```
l = [[1, 0],[1, 2],[2, 9],[3, 0],[3, 8],[3, 1]]

from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()

for a, b in l:
    d.setdefault(a, 0)
    d[a] += b
print(map(list,d.iteritems()))

[[1, 2], [2, 9], [3, 9]]
```